# Match everything inside body tags with regex and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'd like to know if someone can help me with regex on javascript.

So basically I have the following sample of an email body:

```
<body lang="FR" link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72"><div class="WordSection1"><p style="margin:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt">Bonjour,<o:p></o:p></p></div></body>
```

And using regex I need to get only the content between the body tag, how can I do that?

I tried this before (str is the html code above): `str.match(/<body\s[^>]*>(.*?)<\/body>/gi);`

But when I try to get the group 1, using str[1], I always get undefined, any idea why?

Important Note: I'm doing this on ServiceNow and I need to parse the HTML on server side, basically what I have is the HTML code inside a string field.

Comment: Have you tried str[0] ? may be the index starts from 0.

Comment: @Saifullahkhan Using str[0] it returns the whole string, with the body tags too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DOMParser`.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/html");
var body = doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
console.log(body);
```

Comment: I don't think I can do that, I forgot to say one thing which is probably relevant, I'm doing this on ServiceNow and I need to parse the HTML on server side, basically what I have is the HTML code inside a string field.

Comment: Use whatever HTML parsing library you have on the server side. This is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Look this question [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

This should work

```js
var str = '<body lang="FR" link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72"><div class="WordSection1"><p style="margin:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt">Bonjour,<o:p></o:p></p></div></body>'

var myregex = /<body\s[^>]*>(.*?)<\/body>/gi

var match = myregex.exec(str)

console.log(match[1])
```

Comment: It works indeed for that example, I've tried that on a real case and my string there has a lot of more content as well as break lines, and using your code there it returns the following error: Cannot read property '1' of null.

I also forgot to say that the string does not start with <body> tag, it starts with <html> and the <body> is somewhere in the middle and I just want to get the content inside the <body> tags.